# regEx - regExp | tag <a> </a> - with other tag between

Tags: html, regex, vb.net

I'm searching to match all the content between 2 tag `<a` and `</a>`

My page is always the same,

```
<a class="applink" href="myLINK" target="..." onClick="..."><img src="..." border="0" alt="..." title="..." align=bottom hspace=3 width="32" height="32"><br>xxxxx</br></a>
```

A would like match all part of html code where code like this.

so `<a class="applink"  [...] </a>`   (!!!! with the tag `<img` for example --> no [^>]*)

Comment: What do you want to extract? The "xxxxx"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: just a small markup note, `<br>xxxx</br>` is not correct. A line break must always be like this: `<br />`

Comment: sorry i want say : <b>xxxx</b>

Comment: I want all the tag A with class="appLink"

Comment: @annakata - This isn't a duplicate in any way, but I'm sympathetic to your passion. `:)`

Comment: @annakata [Obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4231382/471272): please link to actual answers, not to non-answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML parsing is a bit tricky with regex, but this should work for many cases:

```
<a\s.*?href\s*=\s*"appLink"[^>]*>(.|\s)*?</a>
```

This will match  elements with an href="appLink".

You might want to consider using the .NET XML parsing code.

Comment: I want all the tag A with class="appLink" so if it's <a href=><img src></a> i want also the <img> tag... And can you give me some info about XML parser class ?

Comment: i have remote "new_line" so with '<a class=""appLinks""(.*?)href=""[^>]+>(.*?)</a>' it's ok... But i i want perform this to have only ...href="appl...  or ...href="laun... !  Greats

Answer (score 2):

A better approach here is to use an HTML parser. For example, the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://jsbin.com/enico4/"); // this works!
HtmlNodeCollection links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='appLink']");
```

You can also get each link's HTML if you need it, but `links` is already the collection you need.

```
IEnumerable<string> appLinks = links.Select(link => link.InnerHtml);
```

(the code here is C#, but it should translate easily to VB.Net)

Comment: Thank for you approach. Problem is that if a work with a webBrowser, i can't or i don't know how, joins my httprequest whith this webBrowser because cookies is loss and so WebBrowser ask again an authentification. Bue Thanks for your solution. I have well try an XML parser, but the page is not valid so i have many error :(

Comment: @yrejk - I'm not sure I understand. You already have the HTML, don't you? You use the regex on it. The Agility Pack can take HTML from a string, you don't have to load it from a browser or a web request.

Comment: @yrejk The point here is that you may instantiate the `HtmlDocument` with an HTML *string*, you do not even need to fetch the data from the Web again after you get the HTML data with your WebBrowser.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it for you: `<a .*?</a>`

This does NOT affect tags like <address>, <abbr>, ...

Answer (score -1):

```
<a.*</a>
```

OR

```
<a class="applink".*</a>
```